# awk to output file based on specific rules

Tags: awk

I am to trying use the `awk` below to get the output to look like the desired output and having some trouble with the syntax.  The part I seem to be having trouble with is using those bases `$3` in a specific target `$1` less than 30 reads, outputting that # and calculating the average.  Thank you :).

```
awk '
    {N[$1]++
     T[$1]+=$4
     M[$1]=$2
    }
END     {for (X in N) printf ("%s is %d bases and maps to %s with an average depth"\
                            " of %f reads\n", X, N[X], M[X], T[X]/N[X]);
    }
'  input.txt > output.txt
```

**input**

```
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 1   0
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 2   0
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 3   0
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 4   1
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 5   1
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 6   1
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 7   1
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 8   1
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 9   1
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 10  1
chr1:955542-955763  AGRN:exon.1 11  32
```

**Current output**

```
chr1:955542-955763 is 11 bases and maps to AGRN:exon.1 with an average depth of 3.545455 reads
```

**Desired output**

```
chr1:955542-955763 is 11 bases and maps to AGRN:exon.1 with an average depth of 3.54 reads and there are 10 bases less than 30 reads with an average coverage of 0.63 reads
```

**edit (field description)**

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) print i, $i}' input.txt

1 chr1:955542-955763 (defines the specific target location) - variable N
2 AGRN:exon.1  (defines the name/id of the target location) - variable M
3 1   (defines the exact base on the target)
4 0    (used to calculate the average) - variable T
```

The first part of the output seems to work perfectly it is just adding to that to try and get the second part.  Which is basically, `and there are 10 bases less than 30 reads with an average coverage of 0.63 reads`

where `10` is the last base in `$2` in which there were less than thirty reads. `0.63` is the average of all the #'s in `$4` of those.  I hope this helps and thank you :).

**2-D output**

```
Lo: chr1:955542-955763 is 10 bases and maps to AGRN:exon.1 with an average depth of 0.700000 reads
Hi: chr1:955542-955763 is 1 bases and maps to AGRN:exon.1 with an average depth of **2.909091** reads  ( should be 32 - `$4` is 32 / 1)
```

Comment: It might help those of us who don't speak *"agoraphobic chromium exonese"* (TM) if you told what the columns contain and which ones are supposed to be counted/averaged, and when, in order to deduce the results you want...

Comment: I added an edit section with a field description that I hope will help.  Thank you :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

For a thresholded, 2-D kind of output, I will revert to `GNU awk` for 2-D arrays:

```
gawk '
    {  i=1                 # use second index of 1 for $4 < 30
       if($4>=30)i=2       # use second index of 2 for $4 >= 30
       N[$1][i]++
       T[$1][i]+=$4
       B[$1][i]++
       M[$1][i]=$2
    }
    END {
       for (X in N){
          printf ("Lo: %s is %d bases and maps to %s with an average depth"\
                            " of %f reads\n", X, N[X][1], M[X][1], T[X][1]/B[X][1]);
          printf ("Hi: %s is %d bases and maps to %s with an average depth"\
                            " of %f reads\n", X, N[X][2], M[X][2], T[X][2]/B[X][2]);
       }
    }    ' input.txt
```

**Output**

```
Lo: chr1:955542-955763 is 10 bases and maps to AGRN:exon.1 with an average depth of 0.700000 reads
Hi: chr1:955542-955763 is 1 bases and maps to AGRN:exon.1 with an average depth of 32.000000 reads
```

**Original Answer**

I think you want something like this, which ignores lines where the last field is 30 or more:

```
awk '
    $4 < 30 {
       N[$1]++
       T[$1]+=$4
       B[$1]=$3
       M[$1]=$2
    }
    END {
       for (X in N) printf ("%s is %d bases and maps to %s with an average depth"\
                            " of %f reads\n", X, N[X], M[X], T[X]/B[X]);
    } ' input.txt
```

Comment: That outputs the reads `less than 30`  and there `average`but can it also output the reads `greater than 30` and there `average`?  Thank you :).

Comment: Pleasure... and I have learned a new language - *"agoraphobic chromium exonese"* ;-)

Comment: That's a tricky language to learn and you mastered it :)  Thanks again and for introducing me to `gawk`.

Comment: I thought I understood enough to make a change but can not seem to do so.... in the 2-D output in the Hi the last average should be 32 (`$4` / `3`), since there is only 1 base with a depth of 32.  I was trying to follow the `gawk` but am getting syntax errors.  Thank you :).

Comment: So we are counting the number of lines, not looking at the $3 value in the last line? In that case, it should be `B[$1][i]++` rather than `B[$1][i]=$3` then. I have updated the code.